# Sending mails via SMTP using WordPress on 000webhost

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I have my WordPress (WP) blog installed on 000webhost.com free hosting servers.
WP uses the PHP mail to send emails by default. This WORKS for me. However, the recipient gets a warning that the email was routed VIA srv16.000webhost.com.
**This is exactly my problem. I'd like to use Gmail's SMTP mail, for example, so that the recipient gets it directly from the sender.**

- I tried it both on a dummy blog I have, using 000webhost's free URLs, as well as on my official blog with my own domain, that I host on their servers. Both fail to work with SMTP.
- I thought this might be related to the MX record, so I changed it (for the official blog with my own domain) to be that of Google's apps (ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM). The problem persisted even after 24 hours after that MX change.
- I don't know if it's relevant, but the PHP configuration (phpinfo()) on 000webhost says: SMTP: localhost, smtp_port: 25, OpenSSL support: enabled, OpenSSL Version: OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008.
- I have tested many plugins (including WP Mail SMTP 0.9.1, Cimy Swift SMTP 2.1.1) to activate my SMTP instead of PHP mail. I tried both port 465 with SSL, or 587 with TLS. All plugins at all configurations always failed to send a Test Email. Example error message I got:

`Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to tcp://smtp.gmail.com:587 (Connection timed out)`

`Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]`

Comment: This could be because of a configuration setting imposed by the web host... You should probably talk to them

Comment: Thanks @Pekka, do you have any idea how I can check that configuration to make sure that this is the problem? I can NOT talk to them... that's free hosting...

Comment: These are the settings I used to setup my Gmail account to use 000's servers to send outgoing mail. YMMV with Wordpress/PHP.

Use the same address for outgoing as incoming. My SOMETHING was mx.

    SMTP Server: SOMETHING.000webhost.com
    PORT: 25
    USING: TLS

Answer (score 1):

We wrote a plug-in that should work for you.  It does SMTP mail, throttling, queueing, non-delivery processing.  Works well with gMail.  Give it a look.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mail-queues/

It might be that your provider requires you to use their SMTP server, the plugin should also work in that case.